# RichSnippet Recipe Image not showing up

Tags: wordpress, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I tried to get the image of my recipe to the google search results. But i won't work. 
Does anybody know what i am doing wrong? I can see the url in the Testing Tool, but not in the preview image on top.

Here are the results from the Google Tool:

[Google Structure Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http://vietnam.asiastreetfood.com/vietnamesische-nudelsuppe-mit-rind-pho-bo/)

Appreciate any help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a "article" item type inside your recipe item. I try to remove it and the image show up in the testing tools. But the review aggregate not showing, you have to modify this part too. Hope this will help :)